# image -resize commandline Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick, command-prompt

I've just updated Windows Server 8 to Windows Server 2012 R2 and got a problem with the image -resize command. I've installed ImageMagick but still having the same error

Here's my command

```
FOR  %%a IN (*.jpg) DO convert "%%a" -resize 2000x2586! -define jpg:extent=700k "%productImageDir%\zoom\%%a"
call:doProgress
```

and here's the error I'm getting when I run it on cmd

Invalid Parameter - -resize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Microsoft `CONVERT.EXE` that name-clashes with **ImageMagick** `convert`. Because of your `PATH`, you are calling the Microsoft one which doesn't understand the **ImageMagick** parameters.

The best way to avoid problems is to use `magick` in place of `convert`

```
magick "%%a" -resize 2000x2586! -define jpg:extent=700k "%productImageDir%\zoom\%%a"
```

The second best way to avoid problems is to correct your `PATH` so that the **ImageMagick** directory appears in your `PATH` *before* `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32`.