# Running ImageMagick tool from Python code results in error

Tags: python, imagemagick, subprocess

I need to call ImageMagick `convert` tool from Python. If I'm not using Python and just run such a command in a Windows shell:

```
C:\> convert "C:/Apache24/htdocs/layers/4_projected.tif" "C:/Apache24/htdocs/layers/3_projected.tif" "C:/Apache24/htdocs/layers/2_projected.tif" -combine "C:/Apache/htdocs/layers/432.tif"
```

it works just great. When, however, I try to run it from Python like this:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(["convert", "C:/Apache24/htdocs/layers/4_projected.tif", "C:/Apache24/htdocs/layers/3_projected.tif", "C:/Apache24/htdocs/layers/2_projected.tif", "-combine", "C:/Apache24/htdocs/layers/432.tif"])
```

I get an error message, that says:

> parameter is not allowed: C:/Apache24

I tried also `//`, `\` and `\\` slashes, but got the very same error. So, what may be wrong with that?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43248983/438117). Python's subprocess is calling the wrong `convert` utility.

Comment: That works! Thank you, emcconville!